How does the polynomial kernel in tinygp work?
I am trying to learn to use the tinygp (v 0.3.0) package (Python version 3.11.10 on macOS Sonoma 14.5) but encountering a problem with the linear kernel. I am following one of their tutorials and this is the code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.datasets import co2

data = co2.load_pandas().data
t = 2000 + (np.array(data.index.to_julian_date()) - 2451545.0) / 365.25
y = np.array(data.co2)
m = np.isfinite(t) & np.isfinite(y) & (t < 1996)
t, y = t[m][::4], y[m][::4]

plt.plot(t, y, ".k")
plt.xlim(t.min(), t.max())
plt.xlabel("year")
_ = plt.ylabel("CO$_2$ in ppm")

import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

from tinygp import kernels, GaussianProcess


jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)


def build_gp(theta, X):
    # We want most of our parameters to be positive so we take the `exp` here
    # Note that we're using `jnp` instead of `np`
    amps = jnp.exp(theta["log_amps"])
    scales = jnp.exp(theta["log_scales"])

    # Construct the kernel by multiplying and adding `Kernel` objects
    k1 = amps[0] * kernels.ExpSquared(scales[0])
    
    k2 = (amps[1] * kernels.ExpSquared(scales[1]) * kernels.ExpSineSquared(scale=jnp.exp(theta["log_period"]), gamma=jnp.exp(theta["log_gamma"])))
    
    k3 = amps[2] * kernels.RationalQuadratic(alpha=jnp.exp(theta["log_alpha"]), scale=scales[2])
    
    k4 = amps[3] * kernels.ExpSquared(scales[3])
        
    kernel = k1 + k2 + k3 + k4
    
    return GaussianProcess(
        kernel, X, diag=jnp.exp(theta["log_diag"]), mean=theta["mean"])


def neg_log_likelihood(theta, X, y):
    gp = build_gp(theta, X)
    return -gp.log_probability(y)


theta_init = {
    "mean": np.float64(340.0),
    "log_diag": np.log(0.19),
    "log_amps": np.log([66.0, 2.4, 0.66, 0.18, 2.0]),
    "log_scales": np.log([67.0, 90.0, 0.78, 1.6, 3.0]),
    "log_period": np.float64(0.0),
    "log_gamma": np.log(4.3),
    "log_alpha": np.log(1.2),
    "sigma": jnp.array(1.0)
}

# `jax` can be used to differentiate functions, and also note that we're calling
# `jax.jit` for the best performance.
obj = jax.jit(jax.value_and_grad(neg_log_likelihood))

print(f"Initial negative log likelihood: {obj(theta_init, t, y)[0]}")
print(f"Gradient of the negative log likelihood, wrt the parameters:\n{obj(theta_init, t, y)[1]}")

import jaxopt

solver = jaxopt.ScipyMinimize(fun=neg_log_likelihood)
soln = solver.run(theta_init, X=t, y=y)
print(f"Final negative log likelihood: {soln.state.fun_val}")

t_final = 2055
x = np.linspace(max(t), t_final, 2000)
gp = build_gp(soln.params, t)
cond_gp = gp.condition(y, x).gp
mu, var = cond_gp.loc, cond_gp.variance

plt.plot(t, y, ".k")
plt.fill_between(x, mu + np.sqrt(var), mu - np.sqrt(var), color="C0", alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(x, mu, color="C0", lw=2)

plt.xlim(t.min(), t_final)
plt.xlabel("year")
_ = plt.ylabel("CO$_2$ in ppm")

In practice, they define 4 kernels with the appropriate parameters, sum them together, and proceed using this sum. So far so good. Now, I wanted to try to add another kernel to test the whole thing, and whatever kernel I add, everything keeps working fine. Except with the Polynomial kernel (see here). So, I add the following line
k5 = 1.0 * kernels.Polynomial(scale=1.0, order = 2, sigma=1.0)

and then sum it up to the others. At this point, if I run the code, I get the following error:
ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 56
     52 # `jax` can be used to differentiate functions, and also note that we're calling
     53 # `jax.jit` for the best performance.
     54 obj = jax.jit(jax.value_and_grad(neg_log_likelihood))
---> 56 print(f"Initial negative log likelihood: {obj(theta_init, t, y)[0]}")
     57 print(f"Gradient of the negative log likelihood, wrt the parameters:\n{obj(theta_init, t, y)[1]}")

    [... skipping hidden 20 frame]

Cell In[6], line 37, in neg_log_likelihood(theta, X, y)
     36 def neg_log_likelihood(theta, X, y):
---> 37     gp = build_gp(theta, X)
     38     return -gp.log_probability(y)

Cell In[6], line 32, in build_gp(theta, X)
     28 print("Shape of X:", X.shape)
     30 kernel = k1 + k2 + k3 + k4 + k5
---> 32 return GaussianProcess(
     33     kernel, X, diag=jnp.exp(theta["log_diag"]), mean=theta["mean"])

    [... skipping hidden 3 frame]

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tinygp/gp.py:107, in GaussianProcess.__init__(self, kernel, X, diag, noise, mean, solver, mean_value, covariance_value, **solver_kwargs)
    105     else:
    106         solver = DirectSolver
--> 107 self.solver = solver(
    108     kernel,
    109     self.X,
    110     self.noise,
    111     covariance=covariance_value,
    112     **solver_kwargs,
    113 )

    [... skipping hidden 3 frame]

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tinygp/solvers/direct.py:49, in DirectSolver.__init__(self, kernel, X, noise, covariance)
     38 """Build a :class:`DirectSolver` for a given kernel and coordinates
     39 
     40 Args:
   (...)
     46         and adding ``diag``, but that is not checked.
     47 """
     48 self.X = X
---> 49 self.variance_value = kernel(X) + noise.diagonal()
     50 if covariance is None:
     51     covariance = kernel(X, X) + noise

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tinygp/kernels/base.py:86, in Kernel.__call__(self, X1, X2)
     84 def __call__(self, X1: JAXArray, X2: JAXArray | None = None) -> JAXArray:
     85     if X2 is None:
---> 86         k = jax.vmap(self.evaluate_diag, in_axes=0)(X1)
     87         if k.ndim != 1:
     88             raise ValueError(
     89                 "Invalid kernel diagonal shape: "
     90                 f"expected ndim = 1, got ndim={k.ndim} "
     91                 "check the dimensions of parameters and custom kernels"
     92             )

    [... skipping hidden 4 frame]

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tinygp/kernels/base.py:66, in Kernel.evaluate_diag(self, X)
     59 def evaluate_diag(self, X: JAXArray) -> JAXArray:
     60     """Evaluate the kernel on its diagonal
     61 
     62     The default implementation simply calls :func:`Kernel.evaluate` with
     63     ``X`` as both arguments, but subclasses can use this to make diagonal
     64     calcuations more efficient.
     65     """
---> 66     return self.evaluate(X, X)

    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tinygp/kernels/base.py:177, in Sum.evaluate(self, X1, X2)
    176 def evaluate(self, X1: JAXArray, X2: JAXArray) -> JAXArray:
--> 177     return self.kernel1.evaluate(X1, X2) + self.kernel2.evaluate(X1, X2)

    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tinygp/kernels/base.py:187, in Product.evaluate(self, X1, X2)
    186 def evaluate(self, X1: JAXArray, X2: JAXArray) -> JAXArray:
--> 187     return self.kernel1.evaluate(X1, X2) * self.kernel2.evaluate(X1, X2)

    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tinygp/kernels/base.py:248, in Polynomial.evaluate(self, X1, X2)
    246 def evaluate(self, X1: JAXArray, X2: JAXArray) -> JAXArray:
    247     return (
--> 248         (X1 / self.scale) @ (X2 / self.scale) + jnp.square(self.sigma)
    249     ) ** self.order

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/array_methods.py:743, in _forward_operator_to_aval.<locals>.op(self, *args)
    742 def op(self, *args):
--> 743   return getattr(self.aval, f"_{name}")(self, *args)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/array_methods.py:271, in _defer_to_unrecognized_arg.<locals>.deferring_binary_op(self, other)
    269 args = (other, self) if swap else (self, other)
    270 if isinstance(other, _accepted_binop_types):
--> 271   return binary_op(*args)
    272 # Note: don't use isinstance here, because we don't want to raise for
    273 # subclasses, e.g. NamedTuple objects that may override operators.
    274 if type(other) in _rejected_binop_types:

    [... skipping hidden 12 frame]

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/testgp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py:3308, in matmul(a, b, precision, preferred_element_type)
   3305   if ndim(x) < 1:
   3306     msg = (f"matmul input operand {i} must have ndim at least 1, "
   3307            f"but it has ndim {ndim(x)}")
-> 3308     raise ValueError(msg)
   3309 if preferred_element_type is None:
   3310   preferred_element_type, output_weak_type = dtypes.result_type(a, b, return_weak_type_flag=True)

ValueError: matmul input operand 0 must have ndim at least 1, but it has ndim 0

But I don't understand what I am doing wrong. If I define k5 but don't sum it to the others, there are no errors so I guess the syntax should be correct. I tried to change the parameters but nothing seems to work.
